# how do i get which href is clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML code, how do I get the value of selected  tag here

```
  <div id="myDropdownOptions" onclick="logType()">
          <a href="#about">about</a>
          <a href="#base">base</a>
          <a href="#blog">blog</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the [global Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) will give you the clicked element.

You can then use `textContent` to get the text from it (assuming that is what you want, only form controls (like `input` elements) have `value`s.

```js
function logType() {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDropdownOptions" onclick="logType()">
  <a href="#about">about</a>
  <a href="#base">base</a>
  <a href="#blog">blog</a>
</div>
```

Note that the global Event object is deprecated, so you should replace your `onclick` attribute with the [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and use the event object that is passed as the first argument to the callback instead.

```js
function logType(event) {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
}

document
    .querySelector("#myDropdownOptions")
    .addEventListener("click", logType);
```

```html
<div id="myDropdownOptions">
  <a href="#about">about</a>
  <a href="#base">base</a>
  <a href="#blog">blog</a>
</div>
```